# how to implement a drop down in one of the child components in angular?

Tags: angular

I have an app component which is havng a header component as a child.
I want to implement a drop down list in that header component.The drop down list will consists of a list of colours and as a colour will be selected the background should become of that colour.

ANy idea how can I implement this?
Especially with Material Ui? any ideas?

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of how to set the background colour on a div in different component based on selected option.

See [Medium - sharing data between Angular components](https://medium.com/@chameeradulanga87/sharing-data-between-angular-components-f76fa680bf76) for explanation of @Output usage to pass value to parent.

AppHeader Component html:

```
 <select (change)="updateSelectedStyle($event.target.value)">
    <option *ngFor="let s of styles" [ngValue]="s">{{s}}</option>
 </select>

 </div>
```

AppHeader Component:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit  {

  styles: string[] = [];


import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';



 export class AppHeaderComponent {

  @Output() updateStyleEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();

updateSelectedStyle(value) {
    this.updateStyleEvent.emit(value)
  }

      ngOnInit()
      {
      this.styles = ['red','green'];
      }
    }
```

AppComponent CSS:

```
.red {background:#f00}
.green {background:#0f0}
```

AppComponent:

```
  export class AppComponent {

    selectedStyle:string;

  updateStyle($event) {
    this.selectedStyle = $event
  }
```

AppComponent html:

```
<div [ngClass]="selectedStyle"></div>
    <app-header (updateStyleEvent)="updateStyle($event)"></app-header>
```

**[working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e7mnda) in StackBlitz (hello component = app-header)**

Comment: i have implemented as directed but then i am trying to pass the selectedStyle Value to the parent by referencing.I am able to get the values  of the drop down in the child but not able to change the colour. In app.component.html  <div [ngClass]="child.selectedStyle"><app-header #child></app-header></div>
  <h2>{{title}}</h2>
  <h1>{{child.selectedStyle}}
  </h1>

Comment: I've edited answer to show example using @Output to pass change to selectedStyle variable in parent. Also added link to working example.

Answer (score 0):

You need provide info about selected color from the child comonent to the parent comonent, so the best solution for that will be service.

Or you can use @Output decorator for selected color in child component and get that value in your parent color to set background color.

But 1st solution i more flexible, becouse you can change color from any place in your app.